# What is the procedure to integrate cross toolchain with Redhawk IDE?

Tags: redhawksdr

Following "[How to run waveform developed in REDHawk IDE in my target board ( Zedboard by Xilinx)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453904/how-to-run-waveform-developed-in-redhawk-ide-in-my-target-board-zedboard-by-xi)", a custom OS is developed using Yocto and Redhawk recipes and installed it in Zedboard. SCA application is being developed using Redhawk IDE installed in development PC. To run the same application in custom OS, a cross-toolchain is generated for that environment using "bitbake redhawk-base-image -c populate_sdk" command (source: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/adt-manual/adt-manual.html). Idea is to develop the application in development PC and build it with cross-toolchain. So, now what is the procedure to integrate cross toolchain with Redhawk IDE?

Answer (score 0):

The Yocto Project provides [some tooling for this](https://www.yoctoproject.org/tools-resources/projects/eclipse-ide-plug).

Answer (score 0):

There is little experience in the community with customizing the build-chain in the REDHAWK IDE; ultimately you just want to research updating the build chain in the Eclipse CDT which can you find information about on-line.

The following is provided as a possible approach (one that hasn't been tested).  The current build-chain for the REDHAWK IDE is completely based on the generated build scripts that are a part of all REDHAWK projects:

- "build.sh all" to build
- "build.sh clean" to clean
- "build.sh install" to install

You've no doubt noticed this in the console as you've worked with projects in the IDE. So as long as you modify your project to cross-compile when build.sh is getting invoked, the build portion will happen automatically within the IDE. However, it's another matter to get the IDE to understand that your project is referencing files for the embedded board's operating system, and not the native operating system. Here's a rough outline of what I think you'd need to do:

- Help -> Install New Software

  - Under Mobile and Device Development find and install C/C++ GCC Cross Compiler Support
- Window -> Preferences

  - C/C++ -> Build -> Settings
  - Under Discovery, select CDT Cross GCC Built-in Compiler Settings
  - Modify the command used to get the compiler specs as appropriate for the embedded platform
- Create a new component, get it setup so that when build.sh is run it is cross-compiled for the embedded platform
- Project -> Properties

  - C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols
  - Select Includes tab
  - Select GNU C++
  - Modify include directories as needed for the embedded platform
- C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Includes

  - Select Providers
  - Uncheck CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings
  - Check CDT Cross GCC Built-in Compiler Settings